# Blank space between SearchBar and NavigationBar - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a simple `tableViewController`, a `searchBar` with scopes and a `navigationBar`.

When I click on my `searchBar` I see my scopes and all works. Then I click on a row and I go to my `DetailPage` and the search bar isn't hidden (I don't know why).

So I click *cancel* and then I return to my `tableView`. When I return to my tableView there is a blank space between my `SearchBar` and my `NavigationBar`.

[image: Blank space]

This is my code:

```
      self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Title", "Author", "Location", "Price", "User"]
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller
        })()

 func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        let scopes = resultSearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles
        let currentScope = scopes![resultSearchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: currentScope)
    }
```

Comment: I think adjust ScrollView Insets to false works for you ... your controller attribute inspector uncheck adjust ScrollView Insets

Comment: I have tried but the result is the same

Comment: Have you identified what entity accounts for the margin by logging the `frames`? (_header, insets, searchbar_) What separates your code in `viewDidLoad` from `viewWill/DidAppear`?

Comment: My resultSearchController is in my viewDidLoad method. I don't have viewWill/DidAppear method. The search bar is the problem because when I click that it become bigger because of my scopes.

Comment: set SearchBar position : ( 0 , 24,Width ,Height)

Comment: search bar position doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try to Add

```
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

  self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

in `viewDidload`.

Comment: Nothing. The error is the same. Each time I go to my detail page after using search bar with scopes a blank space is added between navigation bar and table view

Comment: once try by adding one empty label in your main view (above your search bar - i.e. your label should be first control in your view hierarchy)